# Where to get a `BIP32 test pubkey`

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, payment, mycelium-wallet

I would like to create a gateway on MyCelium.com. This is for my testing, so I want to test it out first. But I struggle in getting a `BIP32 test pubkey`.

[image]

There is no documentation on MyCelium.com, neither even Google. It is really frustrating to go through this. Could anybody please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://bip32.org/, there is a selection box in the top right hand corner of the page to choose Bitcoin Testnet. That will generate you an extended private key from a passphrase of your choosing. Note that I recommend you **Do NOT use any keys generated from websites online for real world payments**. But for testing this out it should be fine. Using the default passphrase it generated me:
`tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPd7Uf69XL1XwhmjHopUGep8GuEiJDZmbQz6o58LninorQAfcKZWARbtRtfnLcJ5MQ2AtHcQJCCRUcMRvmDUjyEmNUWwx8UbK`

Once you have generated an extended private key at the top, starting with `tprv`, you can then select "Info: m" in the Derivation Path box, which will show you the extended public master key. In this case it generated:
`tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4WaWSyoBvQwbpLkojyoTZPRsgXELWz3Popb3qkjcJyJUGLnL4qHHoQvao8ESaAstxYSnhyswJ76uZPStJRJCTKvosUCJZL5B`

Again feel free to use this for testing, but please generate an extended key correctly for the mainnet in a secure way, do not use random websites to do it!